# Problem Running ModernCV program

Tags: moderncv

Hello I need help running a program on one of my computers. I updated my MikTex console and refreshed the files but I still get the following error

[image]

I maintain my other computer both windows 10 and update packages the same way. One compiles the pdf the other does not . A little frustrating. Any ideas?

I ran a small program using \usepackage{iftex}. Here is the log output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.15)  15 MAR 2020 12:00
entering extended mode
**./LaTeX1.tex
(LaTeX1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
No file LaTeX1.aux.
\openout1 = `LaTeX1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
[1

{C:/Users/BretS/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(LaTeX1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 411 strings out of 480896
 6776 string characters out of 2908249
 239592 words of memory out of 3000000
 16376 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,130b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10
.pfb>
Output written on LaTeX1.pdf (1 page, 10815 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: you need to use the miktex console to update your package database and update the iftex package (which will give you ifxetex)  possibly need to update  in user and admin mode

Comment: Hi David, I see the package iftex in the database 'packages' and I refreshed as a user and admin but the error still exists. I believe it is updated

Comment: no if you have an up to date iftex then ifxetex will be in your path I don't use miktex, but such issues in miktex seem to be always due to not updating in both user and admin mode if you show your full log in a code block, not a screenshot someone will be able to debug

Comment: Run a small document with \usepackage{iftex} and show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did as you requested and entered the log above.

Comment: A *small* document, not one loading lots of stuff. Use article as class and nothing else apart the iftex (not ifxetex!) package.

Comment: Try running a package repro update and then explicitly install `iftex` if miktex does not automatically. For some reason miktex does not reload the package list from the repro automatically (as least as far as I know, I use TeXLive)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed to article documentclass and the pdf was produced! But I still get an error with modernCV. Sorry about the long output , I am not sure what in the log file you are looking for.

Comment: your iftex.sty is up-to-date. Check if there is a ifxetex.sty in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex`. If not deinstall and reinstall the iftex package (in admin mode), if it is there update the file name database (menu tasks in the console).

Comment: Yes, it is there. I was able update in admin mode but not user mode. The error still exists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it appears to be specific to this computer and the package modernCV. I have two other computers and maintain the MiKTeX distribution the same. I am not a pro at installation and computer science issues but if you can think of anything going on , please let me know. It is a little frustarating but for now I just use the other computers.